# Lumia 930 stuck at Loading after updating to Windows 10 Insider Preview

Tags: update, insider-preview, nokia-lumia-930

My Lumia 930 got stuck at "Loading" after I updated it to Windows 10 Insider Preview. I updated my main (and very used) phone. How do I do a proper install of W10IP on my Lumia 930?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue, my phone was kind of dead for three days, but later on I managed to escape the situation without loosing any data.Steps i followed

1. Remove your Sim card.
2. Try soft resetting(vol down + power button) your phone for 2-3 times then it will may come up with home screen.
3. Do not put your Sim and start in a hurry.
4. Now try uninstalling some of not so imp apps, this issue is basically because of memory management.
5. Now put your Sim, try restarting then it will probably come up with home screen if not then again go for soft reset for 2-3 times, it might solve your problem.

Comment: it did the trick. step 5 - in my case I did soft reset for 6-7 times and finally it come up with home screen.

Answer (score 7):

The solution is to do a complete reset of your phone:

1. Power the device off
2. Press the power key once, device will vibrate
3. Immediately press and hold the Volume Down key
4. Exclamation point will appear, release Volume Down key
5. Press these buttons one at a time in this order: Volume Up, Volume Down, Power, Volume Down
6. Device should vibrate, reboot, show the Nokia flash screen, and then go to the spinning gears install screen.

Comment: Thanks for this - is this procedure actually documented by Microsoft/Nokia/Lumia anywhere?

Comment: It's the standard procedure for a factory reset since WP7.

Answer (score 1):

**The easiest way to get the Start Screen after the "Loading..." bug appear** is to turn on the Airplane Mode, close everything using the task switcher and without soft resetting press the soft reset buttons (power + volume down) just once and the n**ew Feedback form** will pop-up. Just after press the Start button and wait a few seconds and the start will appear. If it doesn't work, retry several times and eventually it will appear. If after a few times it doesn't, soft reset and try again.

I guess the new **Feedback form** is fully responsible of this whole problem. The Airplane Mode just bypasses the Feedback form in online mode. You can turn it off after the Start menu appears. Don't try to touch any settings or any complex app, other way you will fall again in the "Loading..." loop.

**Note**: I have my accent color in Cyan, and the option to display more tiles off.

Original post (by me): https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_install/device-is-not-showing-any-tiles-on-start-screen-on/531e0431-595e-4cbc-9ae2-c50fc696f684?page=29&tm=1432704669960